# Functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I was messing around with it. I was checking out jquery and I wanted to see if I could create something to do the same things. This is my js file

```
  //returns a dom
  var $ = function(selector) {
    return document.querySelector(selector);
  };
  //adds something to the dom
  var append = function(value) {
    this.innerHTML += value;
  };
  //clears dom
  var empty = function() {
    while (this.lastChild) this.removeChild(this.lastChild);
  };
```

When I call `$('#test')` I get the dom with id test. When I call `$('#test').append('hi there')` it works. However when I try `$('#test').empty()` I get a `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).empty is not a function` Any idea why? If I am doing something comletely wrong please let me know. Thanks

Comment: JQuery defines the variable `$`, so when you do `var $ = ...` you're overwriting jQuery's definition.  Your `append` function only works because `this` is the window.

Comment: @Tibrogargan He's not trying to use jQuery, he's trying to implement something similar.

Comment: You're creating separate functions called `append()` and `empty()`, so they will not be available by chaining them from the `$` variable. In other words, you can't do `$.empty` because `empty` is not part of the `$` variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your functions aren't added to the prototype chain of DOM elements, (that wouldn't be a good idea), so they can't be called as methods of DOM elements.

[append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) works, because the DOM node already had a method called `append`, and it has nothing to do with the function you stored in a variable called `append`.

jQuery works by creating a container object that holds a collection of DOM elements and has it's own methods. EG:

```
 var $ = function(selector) {
    var objects = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    return {
      append: function ( ) { 
        // do something to `objects` here
      },
      empty: function ( ) { 

      },
    };
};
```

Comment: When I tried the .append() I was excited because I thought I did something right, guess not. Thanks for your help

Comment: @bena Sorry for the letdown, but better to find out now than later. If you want to continue "messing around" with the code in my answer, you could switch from `querySelectorAll` to `var object = querySelector` (to only select one object) and then use `object.innerHTML` to implement your own append. You could also add a `console.log` in the function to confirm that it is your own append being used and not the built-in one.